# How to make reactjs/flux/react-router spa isomorphic?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I've developed spa with reactjs, flux (no third-party implementations) and react-router.

How can i make it isomorphic now? For SEO and better performance with initial loading.

Comment: This question is way too broad imo. Have you tried googling "reactjs isomorphic"? Have you looked at other Flux implementations that handle isomorphism and how they handle it? Are there any specific questions you've had? Do you have some specific sample code you want to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of resources out there that can help do this. I also took my client only app and made it isomorphic with the help of these resources...

- [React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo)
- [Isomorphic Webapp React Express Coffee](https://benzhang.xyz/reactjs/isomorphic/2015/05/02/isomorphic-webapp-react-express-coffee/)
- [Comprehensive Guide to Building Apps with React JS - Part 1](http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-a-comprehensive-guide-to-building-apps-with-react/)
- [" " Part 2](http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-pt-2-building-react-applications-with-gulp-and-browserify/)
- [Build A Real-Time Twitter Stream with Node and React.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-and-react-js)
- [Going Isomorphic React (slideshow)](http://bensmithett.github.io/going-isomorphic-with-react/#/)
- [Setting Up a Simple Isomorphic React app](http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-simple-isomorphic-react-app/)
- [Serverside React Rendering: Isomorphic JavaScript with ReactJS + Node](http://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-javascript-with-react-node/)

I had a hard time getting mine off the ground but it was definitely worth it! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real life isomorphic application https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall with a lot of isomorphic issues already solved. You can take it as an example.

And here is my post which describes all isomorphic issues in details -  ["The Pain and the Joy of creating isomorphic apps in ReactJS"](http://blog.koorchik.com/isomorphic-react/).